# In LabVIEW Call Library Function Node, what type do I set the parameter to for a pointer to a C++ class?

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, labview

I have written a C++ DLL that will be used to interface with LabVIEW, using the Call Library Function Node.  Now, in my DLL, I have the following function declaration:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall ConnectCamera(Camera *camera, int index);
```

When I fill in the parameters section of the Call Library Function Node in LabVIEW, what do I select as the type for `Camera *camera`?  My only intention is to be able to pass this pointer into other functions such as:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall DisconnectCamera(Camera *camera);
```

From my research, I have seen suggestions to use `Type:Numeric, Data Type:Unsigned Pointer-Sized Integer`, but in scrolling through the possible options I have seen `Type:Instance Data Pointer` and `Type:Adapt to Type, Data Format:Handles by Value`.  Which is the best approach for the user case I described above?

Answer (score 1):

Type:Numeric, Data Type:Unsigned Pointer-Sized Integer

The other settings that you asked about:
1) Adapt To Type and Handles By Value are for LabVIEW types being passed out to C DLL. 
2) Instance Data is the instance data pointer for setup/teardown of the DLL. Read the online help for usage.